# How to pass an array to a sub

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel in Office 365 on Windows 10.

I'm trying to pass an array to a sub but keep getting compile errors

```
Sub PassArrTest(a(6) As Integer) ' This line here gives Compile error:  Expected: ) Error comes up as I'm typing
    
   MsgBox (a(3))
End Sub    

Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim a(6) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 5
    a(i) = i + 1
Next i

PassArrTest (a)



End Sub
```

If I do it like this :-

```
Sub PassArrTest(a() As Integer) ' a declared as a dynamic array
    MsgBox (a(3))
End Sub



Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim a(6) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 5
    a(i) = i + 1
Next i

PassArrTest (a)



End Sub
```

I don't get compile error when typing the code out but when attempting to run I get "compile error Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected"

Is it possible to pass arrays to a sub in VBA and if so what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
Sub PassArrTest(a() As Integer) ' a declared as a dynamic array
    MsgBox a(3)
End Sub

Sub Macro1()
 Dim a(6) As Integer, i As Integer

 For i = 0 To 5
    a(i) = i + 1
 Next i

 PassArrTest a()
 MsgBox passArrBis(a())
End Sub

Function passArrBis(a() As Integer) As Boolean
    If a(3) > 4 Then
        passArrBis = True
    Else
        passArrBis = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Oli: Glad I could help! But in such a case we here vote up a code solving our problem and even more important, we tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code works... :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity why does PassArrTest a() work but PassArrTest(a()) still give an error. I don't understand the difference. I thought these were functionally identical

Comment: @Oli: No, they are not... If the function (not a sub) would return something, it would be mandatory to use parentheses. I will add to the answer code such an example... Added an example relevant from explaining the above statement. Is it clearer now? :)